# Performance tunning using hibernate batch processing

Tags: hibernate, batch-processing

I am trying to retrieve above 300 000 records and update those records in a database using Hibernate batch processing. It's taking around 30 minutes. How can I reduce the time?

Here is my Hibernate configuration:

```
<property nane="connection.provider_class">org.jasypt.hibernate.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider</property> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.encryptor_registered_name">strongHibernateStringEncryptor</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url"></property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema"></property>       
<property name="show_sql">true</property>          
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>       
<property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>   
<property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>    
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
```

I've written 2 Hibernate configuration files for connecting 2 servers (Mock and UAT).

I'm reading a field definition table (FTD), which maintains field names and its values based on transaction reference and process num:

```
for (String srcTxn : bulkTxnSet) {
  Criteria crit = sesMock.createCriteria(FTD.class);
  crit.add(Restrictions.eq("txRefNo", srcTxn ));
  crit.add(Restrictions.eq("processId", "001"));

  // Here is updated code
  ScrollableResults items = crit.scroll();

  while ( items.next() ) {
    FTD e = (FTD)items.get(0);   
    sesUAT.save(e);    

    if ( ++count % 50 == 0 ) {    
      sesUAT.flush();
      sesUAT.clear();
    }   
  }
}
```

I need to get FTD table data from the mock server and save it in the UAT server.

Comment: What are _lacs records_? And without some example code it is hard to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question, if you want to add relevant information. Please explain _lacs records_ and add code, instead of introducing new acronyms. I know a _UAT_, but what is a _FTD table_?

Comment: Now that I know what _lacs_ are, I would say that it could be worse than 166 inserts per second (6 ms per insert). If you really need speed, you should think about using plain SQL, this will really increase the performance. See my remarks on http://fastnate.org as well.

Comment: If you really want performance, don't use hibernate... That would be my advice after 10 years using that library. Direct JDBC is much *much* faster